# How to setup and run Celery on windows?

Tags: django, celery

Hello and thank your for your time

i have a big Django project and i'm developing it in PyCharm on Windows. Right now i need to use smart queries, so i want to add Celery on it. The main problem, that celery dropped support for Windows since v4.0. So my questions is:

1) How can i use rabbit/celery on windows?
2) I have some old answer, that suggest to use old version, that has support for windows, but maybe it has some way with virtual box or other staff to lanch it on windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) to run your Celery, there is an official image in Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/_/celery/

It will take some time to learn how to use Docker though. But it's definitely worth it.

You could use [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/), but in this case you will have to spend some time to configure your Celery environment, at least I didn't find existing Celery Vagrant Box you could use in your project.

Comment: Does Docker really run on Windows?